# Is it possible to set the default command when the `docker exec` command is run on an already running container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-engine

I have a `Dockerfile` with the lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
CMD ["hello"]
```

When I run the `exec` command on an running container I expect:

```
docker exec -it running_container world
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: "world": executable file not found in $PATH
```

How can I make it echo `world`?

Answer (score 3):

You can

`docker exec -it container_id echo hello`

Keep in mind that docker exec just launches commands, like some

`cat file`

or

`echo abc >> /etc/abc.def`

or

`sed regex file`

or a shell

Docker exec has no relationship with the ENTRYPOINT or CMD of the Dockerfile

Comment: "Docker exec has no relationship with the ENTRYPOINT or CMD of the Dockerfile" - Thank you, thatis what I was wondering. Do you happen to have a link to any docs per chance?

Comment: extract from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/ `The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container.` just a command, any command, they never reference the ENTRYPOINT or the CMD